# Firebase ML Kit Android - Invalid API Key

Tags: android, firebase, ocr, api-key, firebase-mlkit

I have an Android App where I am using the Document Text Recognition API. This is a cloud based API for which I have a Firebase Blaze Plan enabled - as required for using Cloud Based APIs. I have all the prerequisites listed in the documentation and have enabled Cloud APIs in my Firebase Console.

However, I am still getting the following error:

```
W/System.err: com.google.firebase.ml.common.FirebaseMLException: 400 Bad Request
{
  "code": 400,
  "errors": [
    {
      "domain": "global",
      W/System.err: "message": "API key not valid. Please pass a valid API key.",
      "reason": "badRequest"
    }
  ],
  "message": "API key not valid. Please pass a valid API key.",
  "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
}
```

I don't understand why. I downloaded the correct `google-services.json` file. I crossed check all my dependencies and I have the Blaze Plan on my project enabled. Why am I still getting this error in my app?

**Here is the code for more reference (Android - Kotlin):**

```
private fun analyzeImage(uri: Uri) {
    val image: FirebaseVisionImage
    try {
        image = FirebaseVisionImage.fromFilePath(this, uri)
        image.bitmap.run { Log.i("Image Size", "Width: $width | Height: $height") }

        val options = FirebaseVisionCloudDocumentRecognizerOptions.Builder().setLanguageHints(listOf("en")).build()
        val dtr = FirebaseVision.getInstance().getCloudDocumentTextRecognizer(options)
        dtr.processImage(image)
            .addOnSuccessListener { doOCR(it); btnGetPhoto.isEnabled = true }
            .addOnFailureListener { it.printStackTrace(); btnGetPhoto.isEnabled = true }
    } catch (ioe: IOException) {
        Log.e("GetImage:Failed", "Failed to get image from uri", ioe)
    }
}

private fun doOCR(fvtResult: FirebaseVisionDocumentText) {
    tvResultText.text = buildString {
        for (block in fvtResult.blocks) {
            for (para in block.paragraphs) {
                append("${para.text} -> [")
                para.boundingBox?.run { append("L: $left, T: $top, R: $right, B: $bottom ]") }
                append("\n\n")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> How do I get rid of this error?

Comment: I suggest contact Firebase support directly for troubleshooting assistance.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support